# How to exclude .cs files during checkout in Jenkins?

Tags: svn, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

Is there any way to exclude .cs files while checkout from SVN in jenkins? I need to fetch only the files needed for release not all the files used in development. So the workspace should contains only the design files and dll.

Answer (score 0):

Several options come to my mind:

- Specify the Subversion repository URL in such way to check out, only specific `release` directory, such as `http://svn.repo.org/repos/project/release/`.
- Use [Workspace Cleanup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin) to remove unnecessary files.
- Try out proposed [feature](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25273) for Subversion Plugin which supposedly implements checkout using sparse checkout (**be aware that this is not official release and can contain bugs/regressions**).

Comment: There are no release directory but only branches/tags available where All the files will be available.  Will the third option supports exclude files?